# операторы сравнения js не понимаю какое свойство не дописал

Tags: javascript

не могу понять какое свойство не дописал

сама задача:

Дан select s-100. По нажатию кнопки, выведите value выбранного option в out-10.

```js
let input10 = document.querySelector('s-100');
let out10 = document.querySelector(".out-10");

function f10() {
  if (input10 == 'six') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if (input10 == 'seven') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if (input10 == 'eleven') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if (input10 == 'nine') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  }
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = f10;
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
  <select class="s-100">
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
    <option value="11">eleven</option>
    <option value="9">nine</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="button-primary b-10">Task-10</button>
<div class="out-10"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может так?

```js
let input10 = document.querySelector('.s-100');
let out10 = document.querySelector('.out-10');
document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = () => out10.innerText = input10.value;
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
   <select class="s-100">
      <option value="6">six</option>
      <option value="7">seven</option>
      <option value="11">eleven</option>
      <option value="9">nine</option>
   </select>
 </div>
 <button class="button-primary b-10">Task-10</button>
 <div class="out-10"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Основная ошибка, вы забыли **точку** в `querySelector`

```
//              тут должна быть точка ↓ class же ведь
let input10 = document.querySelector('s-100');
```

В условие вы пытаетесь сравнить `элемент` с `одним из "текстовым содержимым" option`.
А нужно сравнить `"текстовое содержимое" выбранного option` с выше указанным.

```js
let input10 = document.querySelector('.s-100');
let out10 = document.querySelector('.out-10');

function f10() {
  let t = input10.options[input10.selectedIndex].text; // получаем текущее "текстовое содержимое" выбранного option.
  if(t == 'six') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if(t == 'seven') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if(t == 'eleven') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  } else if(t == 'nine') {
    out10.textContent += input10.value;
  }
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = f10;
```

```html
<div class="form-control">
  <select class="s-100">
    <option value="6">six</option>
    <option value="7">seven</option>
    <option value="11">eleven</option>
    <option value="9">nine</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="button-primary b-10">Task-10</button>
<div class="out-10"></div>
```